# How do you round a float into a decimal place of my choice (python)?

Tags: python

I am doing projects were I need to enter exact change and when I have to multiply a float by other numbers it will not round to the nearest hundredth. I need to know how to round into a specified decimal place.

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python rounding", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: here is a [start](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.aroundl) on your research journey

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in function [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#round) like this:

```
In [1]: value = 22.2222222222
In [2]: num_decimal_places = 2
In [3]: rounded = round(value, num_decimal_places)
In [4]: rounded
Out[4]: 22.22
```